# How do you affect someone NOT holding an item in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As the title suggests, I'm confused on how I can affect someone not holding an item.

In my pvp map, I want a certain class to be able to give everyone not holding the **sugar** named **Spell: Freeze** with slowness 10 for 3 seconds. I had a thought process on how to do it but nothing works. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: would you know how it would work if you wanted to do the same thing if they were holding an item?

Comment: Don't have the time to build and test this, but you should use repeating command blocks setting scoreboard values on players holding the item, then `score_Name=0` to test for players whose score hasn't changed. Anyone reading this, feel free to use what I've said to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first answer, bear with me.

When selecting for players via NBT information, you need to use a /scoreboard command.

To tag all players holding the sugar:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add NoEffect {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:sugar",tag:{display:{Name:"Spell: Freeze"}}}}
```

Then, to give the effect to all players who aren't holding that item:

```
/execute @a[tag=NoEffect] ~ ~ ~ /effect @a[tag=!NoEffect] slowness 3 10
```

Finally, to make sure people who aren't holding the sugar anymore don't get excepted:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a remove NoEffect
```

Feel free to expand on this.
(NOTE: This method gives the players the effect for as long as any player is holding the sugar)

Comment: Using your format, ive been able to make a paper that gives the player holding said paper snowballs... My only issue is that it gives them like _**1 trillion**_ snowballs a second.... Is there I can do this, but only give them like 1 stack every 3 seconds while they hold the paper...? The paper is named **Scroll of Rekindling** if you'd like to add me on any forms of social media to keep in contact for future reference questions, as you seem to know your stuff: discord: _LowlySquire#0554_ SC: _dgmp0401_